# how do I override a standard action

Tags: delphi, taction

I have a situation where I need to change the standard popup menu items/actions for cut/copy/paste.
Complicated, but basically, the local clipboard isn't available, so I need to somehow mimic the right click popup menu. I figured the best ways to do that would be to somehow override the actions themselves.
Anyone have a good, clear idea about how to go about that?

Comment: This sounds like an [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/). The menu items in question are implemented by the OS itself, not by the VCL. The only way to change them is to replace the entire popup menu with a custom one, ie by assigning a `TPopupMenu` to a control's `PopupMenu` property. But, if the clipboard is not available (why?), I would expect the OS to omit/disable those standard actions from the default menu. Can you explain your actual situation better? Perhaps provide an actual example of what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: I am using CybeleSoft VirtualUI to deploy my desktop application to the cloud.  The clipboard on that is a bit 'weird', where the clipboard is a 'remote' clipboad, vs a 'local' clipboard.  Ctrl keys (ctrl-c, ctrl-v) still work correctly, but the right click popup does not.  'paste' is disabled, and the other editing functions don't work.